# TFT 2.4 blank screen

Tags: raspbian

I purchased a Tontec 2.4 TFT on dealextreme, with the adapter. I connected it to the raspberry like this:

[image]

After following step by step the instructions (from here: [Instructions](http://helloraspberrypi.blogspot.com.es/2014/01/setup-tontec-24-inch-tft-lcd-240x320.html))

My screen is always blank, either I run the program that is supposed to get the screen working or not, and when it's supposed to work it doesn't it just stays blank.

Any suggestion?

Comment: I don't see connection instruction in the link you provided but the red stripe on the cable usually denotes pin one, but it doesn't look like the red stripe is aligned to pin one on the Pi. Are you sure you have the connection right?

Comment: i tested it on the other way and i get the same result :(

Comment: you may have killed it if you connected it backward. Which way is supposed to be connected?

Comment: after searching I found an user guide, which had this image:
<a href="http://imgur.com/K5zUke9"><img src="http://i.imgur.com/K5zUke9.png" title="source: imgur.com" /></a>

The fist time I plugged in the cable was in the correct form and it didn't work either

Comment: The image above and the one on imgur don't match. The red strip above is on the ethernet side of the board and the one you linked to on imgur has it toward the sd card end.

Comment: yep i connect it wrong, after configuring it right again the screen still doesn't work , also there's a program 'lcd demo' that comes with the manual but i cant compile it

Comment: As I said previusly you may have killed the screen connecting it wrong, To help you with the compile issue we will need more details, what is the specific error etc. a link to the manual would help as well.

Comment: The manual is this: https://www.scribd.com/doc/244153597/RPI-GPIO-TFT-LCD-Adapter-User-Guide-pdf

I just do the make command (dunno why it says to do "make Demand") but thus appears:

http://i.imgur.com/Qfhn0Hs.png

Comment: Have you installed wiringpi? what happens when you type make demand (demand will be a build target in the make file. This may handle downloading the wiringpi dependency

Comment: I'm getting this now, as you could see I tried the Demand make with no result 

http://i.imgur.com/ZZljc5z.png

Comment: according to this page http://www.ittgroup.ee/en/content/6-juhendid/42-raspberry-pi-juhendid it is in Estonain, but i used google translate to confirm my suspicion that it appears to be a problem with wiringpi. Have you installed wiring pi? pop the text from the link above into google translate.

Comment: so much thanks for the help, but seems that is broken (my fault) since i could compile and execute the program and the screen doesn't respond, I guess I should try buying another one. So much thank you Steve for having patience with a newbie like me and all the help you gave me :D

Comment: Glad I could help. May I make a suggestion as a newbie perhaps you should look for a supplier with better support and documentation. Maybe take a look at https://www.adafruit.com/search?q=pitft&b=1 they have good support and usually a complete tutorial for their parts. The extra cost will be offset by the ease of use and support. FYI you can also accept your own answer - there is even a badge for doing so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I broke the screen by connecting it the wrong way, to fix the lcddemo issue that comes with the manual follow these instructions provided by Steve:

http://www.ittgroup.ee/en/content/6-juhendid/42-raspberry-pi-juhendid

(if you cant compile lcddemo giving you error "setPrecision" on lcd.c, you will have to edit the .c file by commenting the switch (precision) method)